# Store a value into every element of an array: converting a C do{}while loop to MIPS asm

Tags: c++, assembly, mips, qtspim

I need to convert this C++ function into MIPS assembly:

```
int set(int a[], int n, int v)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    do {
      a[i++] = v;
    } while ( i < n);
    return i;
}
```

where the address of the array is in `$a0`, n is in `$a1`, and v is in `$a2`.
This is my attempt at writing the function in MIPS, but I get "instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400054." in main (provided by my professor) there is a call `jal set` which is supposed to call the `set` function and I'm pretty sure my error has something to do with that. I also don't know if I successfully converted the function. This is my attempt:

```
.text
set:
    li      $t0, 0
    addi    $t0, $t0, 0
    sll     $t1, $t0, 2
    add     $t1, $t1, $a0
L1: lw      $t1, 4($t1)
    sw      $a2, 0($t1)
    blt     $t0, $a1, L1
```

I'm using QTSPIM, if that matters at all. I appreciate any help and if you have any advice to pass along for MIPS programming, that would be great too.

UPDATE:

The files are being linked now, but I'm getting an infinite loop of "Exception occurred at PC=0x004000f0" and "Bad address in data/stack read: 0x00000000." This is my updated file:

```
.text
.globl set
set:    addi    $t0, $t0, 0     #i = 0;
         sll    $t1, $t0, 2     #offsets 4 * i
         add    $t1, $t1, $a0       #pointer to a[i]
L1:       lw    $t1, 4($t1)     #a[i++]
          sw    $a2, 0($t1)     #a[i++] = v
         blt    $t0, $a1, L1        #continue the loop as long as i < n
```

Why is it that my code has to be in `.globl`? And what's the purpose of `.text`?

Comment: Why not compile the code (`gcc -O1 -g -o test.o -c test.cpp`) and then `objdump -S test.o`?

Comment: It sounds like that would be cheating.  Besides, why bother creating a `.o` just to disassemble it, when you could create the `.s` (`gcc -O1 -g -o test.s -S test.cpp`)?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? This is what we have compilers for.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Homework probably!

Comment: You need to make `set` globally visible so the linker can see it.  Use a `.globl` https://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-as-en-4/global.html

Comment: What are you doing with the `li` and `addi`? Seems like the `addi` is redundant. Did you mean `addi $t0, $a0, 0`? If so, then the `li` is redundant. As you have it, `$t0 = 0` after those lines and `$t1` will be 0 after the `sll`. But none of this is related to your undefined symbol error. We'll need to see (at least a part of) your professors code to tell you what's causing it.

Comment: I don't know what `objdump -S` does. I've been writing my `.s` files in notepad

Comment: Don't cheap OP. Your professor will know from the assembly that you very likely didn't write it.

Comment: I'm not looking for the answer. I just need guidance because my professor can hardly speak english and I don't understand assembly. I've been trying to teach myself with the book and tutorial videos but I'm still not getting it

Comment: @FranciscoEscobar, see the comment by pat. I think (s)he has the answer.

Comment: A [really] good rule of thumb: put a comment on every inst line [except `.text`, `.globl`, etc] that specifies _intent_. That is, what's going on in problem oriented terms. That way, you can track your logic vs implementation. (i.e.) Is your logic correct or is the inst wrong?

Comment: Where would the `.globl` go in my code? Would it replace `.text`?

Comment: `.globl set` is in addition to `.text` and should _follow_ it. Or, more correctly, it should _precede_ `set:` [on a different line]

Comment: To add to @Craig's comment/rule of thumb, you should also include a register index before a function that explains how you're using each register. Here's a sample: http://pastebin.com/dxN6ZTf7

Comment: `.text` specifies that what follows will be linked into the _text_ segment [for code]. `.globl set` says make the label `set` globally visible to the linker. In your code, you have a second label `L1` that you want to keep private. In C, default linkage for `set()` is global [unless you do `static int set(...)`]. In asm, _everything_ is private [to the file] unless a label also has a `.globl` directive [asm has _no_ `.static`]. In a more complex function, you could have many L1,L2,L3,... labels that are just internal jump targets. Tedious to "mark them static", so static/private is default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there were a few problems.

The corrected code is at the bottom. There are actually two ways to do it, based upon how literal the translation from the C code needs to be. Part of your conceptual problem may have been that you were trying to combine parts from the two methods.

You collapsed your first two instructions from your original code into one, based on comment feedback [as duplicate] (e.g. `li` then `addi`). But, if using only one, the `li` is correct because `addi` adds the register to itself but you can't rely on the initial value being zero.

The `sll` is shifting a register that has a zero value in it, so the inst isn't doing anything.

To load `t1` with `a0`, you'd use `add $t1,$a0,0` [or `add $t1,$a0,$zero`]

The `lw` served no purpose [The C code does not load `a`, so why should asm?].

But, I switched this all around a bit because the loop still wouldn't have worked correctly.

There was no return after your `blt` so even if the loop worked, it would "fall off the edge of the world". Each *called* asm routine [one that is invoked like `jal set`] must have an *explicit* return statement, which is `jr $ra`

NOTE: In MIPS asm, the `a*` [argument registers] *can* be modified by the *callee*, so loop on `a0` rather than `t1` (i.e. caller *expects* that they will be trashed)

---

Anyway, here's the corrected code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .text

    .globl  set
set:
    li      $t0,0                   # i = 0
L1:
    sw      $a2,0($a0)              # a[i] = v
    add     $a0,$a0,4               # advance pointer
    add     $t0,$t0,1               # ++i
    blt     $t0,$a1,L1              # continue the loop as long as i < n
    jr      $ra                     # return
```

---

If your original C function had been something like:

```
int
set(int *a, int n, int v)
{
    int *end;

    end = a + n;
    for (;  a < end;  ++a)
        *a = v;

    return n;
}
```

Then, this would have been a more literal translation:

```
    .text

    .globl  set
set:
    sll     $a1,$a1,2               # convert int count to byte length
    add     $a1,$a0,$a1             # end = a + length

L1:
    sw      $a2,0($a0)              # *a = v
    add     $a0,$a0,4               # ++a
    blt     $a0,$a1,L1              # continue the loop as long as a < end

    jr      $ra                     # return
```

---

IMO, both methods are acceptable implementations of the original C function. The first is more literal in that it preserves the [concept of] the index variable `i`. But, it has an extra instruction that the second doesn't.

An optimizer would probably produce the same code (i.e. the second asm) regardless of which C function it was translating (MIPS does not have the powerful index addressing modes that `x86` asm does).

So, which is "correct" may depend upon how much a stickler your prof is.

---

*Side note:* Notice the style changes between my two examples. That is, code changes aside, adding some blank lines to improve clarity.

---

Just for completeness, here's the `main` function I created when testing:

```
    .data
arr:    .space  400                 # allocate more space than count

    .text

    .globl  main
main:
    la      $a0,arr                 # get array pointer
    li      $a1,10                  # get count
    li      $a2,3257                # value to store

    jal     set

    li      $v0,1                   # exit syscall number
    syscall
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> If in the loop `a[i++] = v`, would I place the `add $t0, $t0, 1` line before the `sw $a2, 0($a0)`?

No, you would do that if the C code was `a[++i] = v`. Perhaps, the best way to view this is to simplify the C code first.

`a[i++] = v` is actually:

```
a[i] = v;
i += 1;
```

And, `a[++i] = v` is actually:

```
i += 1;
a[i] = v;
```

Now, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the lines of C code and asm instructions.

> When would I use the `sll`? I was reading examples and I noticed people usually do `sll $t1, $t0, 2` when they're going to use a counter to go through an array.

Yes. If you look closely at my *second* implementation, it uses `sll` in that manner. Also, it would be the way I would code the loop even when given the original C code.

> Would I use the `lw` if the C code said something like `int x = a[0]`?

Yes, exactly.

---

Another way to prototype asm is to convert the C code into "very dumb C".

That is, only `if` of the simplest form: `if (x >= y) goto label`. Even `if (x < y) j = 10` is off limits.

No function scoped variables or function argument variables--only global variables that are the register names.

No complex expressions. Only simple ones like `x = y`, `x += y`, or `x = y + z`. Thus, `a = b + c + d` would be too complex.

Register variables function as both integer values and *byte* pointers. So, when adding to a register being used as a pointer, it's like adding to a byte pointer, so to increment through an `int` array, you have to add `4`.

The actual difference between a byte pointer and `int` pointer only matters when you do a load/store operation: `lw/sw` for `int` and `lb/sb` for byte.

So, here's my second C function recoded as "dumb":

```
// RETURNS: number of elements changed
int
set(void)
// a0 -- "a" (pointer to int array)
// a1 -- "n" (number of elements in "a")
// a2 -- "v" (value to set into "a")
{

    v0 = a1;                            // set return value

    a1 <<= 2;                           // convert int count to byte length
    a1 += a0;                           // point to one past end of array

L1:
    *(int *)a0 = a2;                    // store v at current array location
    a0 += 4;                            // point to next array element
    if (a0 < a1) goto L1;               // loop back until done

    return;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> In your first implementation, is `add $a0, $a0, 4` the equivalent to using `sll` in the second implementation?

Not quite. The key thing to remember is in C, when we add one to a pointer [or index it with `i`], the compiler will generate an increment/add instruction that adds the `sizeof` of the *type* the pointer is defined as.

That is, for `int *iptr`, specifying `iptr += 1` will generate `add $a0,$a0,4` because `sizeof(int)` is 4. If we had `double *dptr`, `dptr += 1`, the compiler would generate `add $a0,$a0,8` because `sizeof(double)` is 8

This is a powerful "convenience" that the C compiler provides because it allows arrays, pointers, indexes to be used interchangeably.

In asm, we must do manually what the C compiler would do for us automatically.

Consider the following: We have a value that is the count of the number of *elements* in an array, call it `count`. Now, we want to know how many bytes the array will take up. We'll call that `len`. Here's the C code to determine that for various types:

```
char *arr;
len = count * sizeof(char);
len = count * 1;
len = count << 0;
//  sll $a1,$a1,0

short *arr;
len = count * sizeof(short);
len = count * 2;
len = count << 1;
//  sll $a1,$a1,1

int *arr;
len = count * sizeof(int);
len = count * 4;
len = count << 2;
//  sll $a1,$a1,2

double *arr;
len = count * sizeof(double);
len = count * 8;
len = count << 3;
//  sll $a1,$a1,3
```

> From what I understand, using sll sets i as a counter for ints so it increments i and also iterates the array

No. `sll` is merely MIPS's "shift left logical" instruction and you use it when you need the equivalent of C's `<<` operator.

What you're thinking of is how `sll` *can be used* to achieve that effect.

To iterate through an array of `int`, we increment the *index* by 1 but we must also increment the array pointer by 4. This is what my first asm example did. The termination condition was `index >= count`.

In my second asm example, I eliminated the separate index variable by converting the element count into a byte length (via the `ssl`), adding in the array address. Now `$a1` had the address of the last element of the array + 1, and the termination condition was `current_address >= last_element_plus_1`. Note that current_address (`$a0`) still had to be incremented by 4 (`add $a0,$a0,4`)

One important thing to remember is that asm instructions [particularly MIPS] are simple (i.e. *dumb*). They do only one thing at a time. A single C assignment statement could generate some 20 instructions if the statement were complex enough. It's how the asm instructions get combined that produces the more complex results.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just have a couple questions. If in the loop `a[i++] = v`, would I place the `add $t0, $t0, 1` line before the `sw $a2, 0($a0)`? When would I use the `sll`? I was reading examples and I noticed people usually do `sll $t1, $t0, 2` when they're going to use a counter to go through an array. Would I use the `lw` if the C code said something like `int x = a[0]`? Thanks again for the help

Comment: Okay that makes so much sense thanks again. I'm going to dumb down the code as much as possible to make it easier to convert. In your first implementation, is  `add $a0, $a0, 4` the equivalent to using `sll` in the second implementation? From what I understand, using `sll` sets `i` as a counter for ints so it increments `i` and also iterates the array, while the `add $a0, $a0, 4` does that but pointing from `a[0]`, then to `a[1]`, and so on. Am I close?

Comment: Note that `blt` between two registers is a pseudo-instruction for `slt` / `bnez`.  Normally you want to do `bne p, endp, .loop` when you know your end-pointer will be exactly equal at some point, not possibly-misaligned.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8WdYTWdva - GCC makes the same pointer-increment asm, using BNE after I change `i < n` to `i != n`.  (I guess because of the possibility of negative `n`; handling large `n` with a more efficient loop would branching for the negative-`n` case.  Or really for `n<2` so you could unroll...)