# How to calculate mode of array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Been trying since a day to calculate mode of an array in MIPS? I really cant figure out!

Comment: Do it in C first, then translate to assembly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your code attempts.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the mode of a list of sorted integers in an array, start off with the first element of the array and loop through the whole array.
We keep 5 registers to help us find the mode of elements;

1. Keep the value of the previous element of the array.
2. A pointer to point to the element which is being traversed.
3. A register to keep the count of elements that are repeated in array.
4. A register to keep the value of register
5. A register to keep count of current mode.

In ModeLoop, traverse through the array and as soon as a new element is encountered, jump to the updateifneeded block of instructions.
If the count of current mode is greater than the earlier mode count, jump to changeMode,
where you change the value of mode and also the count of mode.
After completing updateifneeded block, the `back` block is executed where the individual count of
the current mode is increased and the loop index is incremented by 1 (and array pointer is incremented by 4).
The register containing the previous element is updated with the value that we just traversed.

```
.data
modeState:    .asciiz "Mode:"
newline: .asciiz "\n"
array:   .word 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4
         .word 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6
         .word 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10
length:  .word 30
mode: .word 0
    
.text
.globl main
main:


#loop through the array to calculate mode

la $t0 array #array's starting address
li $t1 0     #loop index, i=0
lw $t2 length  #length
li $t4, 1 #previous
li $t6, 1 #intial
li $t7, 0 #individualCount
li $t8, 0 #modeValue
li $t9, 0 #modeCount

ModeLoop:
lw $t5 ($t0)   #get array[i]

#when a new value in encountered in the array
bne $t4 ,$t5 , updateifneeded

back:
addi $t7 $t7 1 #individualcount++
addi $t1 $t1 1 #i = i+1
add $t0 $t0 4 #update array address
li $t4 ,0
addi $t4 , $t5, 0

blt $t1 $t2 ModeLoop


#printing mode statement
li $v0,4
la $a0, modeState
syscall

move $a0 $t8
li $v0 1
syscall

#giving space of a line
li $v0,4
la $a0, newline
syscall


li $v0 10
syscall
.end main

updateifneeded:
#if the count greater that earlier mode count
bgt $t7, $t9, changeMode
next:
li $t6 ,0
addi $t6 , $t5, 0
#reintializing individual count
li $t7, 0
j back

changeMode:
#changing modevalue
li $t8 ,0
addi $t8 , $t4, 0
#changing modeCount
li $t9 ,0
addi $t9 , $t7, 0
j next
```

Comment: Good algorithm for a sorted array, but for coding style, it's a lot nicer to indent instructions to the right of labels, so it's easier to see the block structure.  Also, some of the details could be more efficient.  e.g. instead of incrementing a counter up to a length, your loop condition can check the pointer you already have `do{} while( p != endp )`.  Calculate an end-pointer once outside the loop like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35399176)  (Or in this case, just put a label at the end of the array and `la` that instead of using `lw` on a hard-coded length)

Comment: Also, you don't need to zero a register before overwriting it.  In `changeMode`, just use `addi $t8, $t4, 0` to overwrite the old value, without doing `li $t8, 0` first.  (Or use `move $t8, $t4`, which is a simpler way of writing the same `addi` instruction.)

Comment: Also, `back` and `next` are not very clear names when you have this many different blocks.  Instead of `back`, a name like `modeLoop_afterUpdate` would be clearer.  (But long to type and read.)

Comment: @SamraNorman Welcome to SO! OP hasn't said anything about the nature of the array, so I'm not sure we can assume it's sorted already. Thanks for the descriptive answer, though.